# Ошибка при импорте переменной

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Vuex: Из файла в месте с модулем экспортируются константы:

```
import {ERROR, START, SUCCESS} from "~types/loading";

const MUTATION_START = 'MUTATION_START';
const MUTATION_SUCCESS = 'MUTATION_SUCCESS';
const MUTATION_ERROR = 'MUTATION_ERROR';
export const MUTATION_TITLE = 'MUTATION_TITLE';

export default {
    namespaced: true,
    state: {
        title: null,
        status: null,
        error: null,
        data: null
    },
    mutations: {
        [MUTATION_START](state) {
            state.status = START;
        },
        [MUTATION_SUCCESS](state, payload) {
            state.status = SUCCESS;
            state.data = payload;
        },
        [MUTATION_ERROR](state, payload) {
            state.status = ERROR;
            state.error = payload;
        },
        [MUTATION_TITLE](state, payload) {
            state.title = payload;
        }
    },
    actions: {
    },
    getters: {
        start: state => {
            return state.status === START;
        },
        success: state => {
            return state.status === SUCCESS;
        },
        error: state => {
            return state.status === ERROR;
        },
        title: state => {
            return state.title;
        }
    }
}
```

При попытке импортировать MUTATION_TITLE, вылетает ошибка:

> Cannot read property 'getters' of undefined

---

Вынес константы в отдельный файл. Может у кого-нибудь будут другие идеи?

Comment: Как Вы импортируете константу `MUTATION_TITLE` и где? Не встречал конструкции: `[MUTATION_TITLE](state, payload)`. Для чего она используется?

Comment: @hedgehogues, `[MUTATION_TITLE](state, payload)` вариант [computed свойств](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015)

Comment: я ее импортирую во Vue компоненте.